# Date Object algorithm to return date of nearest bi-weekly day of week

Tags: javascript, algorithm, datetime

**Objective**: Automatically display the date of an upcoming bi-weekly event. In this case, every Saturday. Ideally by modifying existing code.

e.g. If there is an event July 9, and today is July 11, the next event will be July 23. If today is July 24th, next event is Aug 6, and so on...

**Problem**: How to calculate it's date? (I assume a reference starting date will be needed, e.g. July 9, 2016)

**Background / Existing code**: Calculate the date of a nearest given day of the week. (e.g. if today is Monday the 14th, whats the date of the upcoming Saturday?). NOTE: In this case, the event is every Friday & Saturday. We display the dates for upcoming Friday and Saturday. BUT I wanted to make sure the dates displayed always fell on the same weekend. (If today is Saturday, FRI date should be yesterday, and SAT date should be today).

```
(function() {

  // Today's date
  var startingDate = new Date();

  // Find date of nearest day of week
  function dateOfNearestDay(startingDate, nearestDay) {

    // Date object to work with inside the function
    var nearestTime = new Date(startingDate.getTime());

    // If today is Sat, use last Fri's date, else calculate date of nearest day
    if (startingDate.getDay() === 6 && nearestDay === 5) {

      nearestTime.setDate((startingDate.getDate() + (7 + nearestDay - startingDate.getDay()) % 7) - 7);

    } 
    else {

      nearestTime.setDate(startingDate.getDate() + (7 + nearestDay - startingDate.getDay()) % 7);

    }

    return nearestTime;
  }

  // Format date as needed for display
  function getMonthAndDay(date) {

    // Array to store month names for translation
    monthNames = ['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'Apr.', 'May', 'Jun.', 'Jul.', 'Aug.', 'Sep.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.'];

    return monthNames[date.getMonth()]+ " " + date.getDate();
  }

  // Get date object of nearest Friday and Saturday
  var friday = dateOfNearestDay(startingDate, 5);
  var saturday = dateOfNearestDay(startingDate, 6);

  var fridayDate = document.getElementById('friday');
  var saturdayDate = document.getElementById('saturday');

  // Write month & day of nearest day
  fridayDate.textContent = getMonthAndDay(friday);    
  saturdayDate.textContent = getMonthAndDay(saturday);

}());
```

Comment: what will it show on july 23? the next to next saturday date or date of that day?

Answer (score 0):

The function `nextEvent` for a given date `today` and known date of the `event` computes the next bi-weekly recurring event after `today` or `today`:

```js
// Today's date
var startingDate = new Date();
startingDate.setDate(startingDate.getDate());

// Find date of nearest day of week
function dateOfNearestDay(startingDate, nearestDay) {

    // Date object to work with inside the function
    var nearestTime = new Date(startingDate.getTime());

    // If today is Sat, use last Fri's date, else calculate date of nearest day
    if (startingDate.getDay() === 6 && nearestDay === 5) {

      nearestTime.setDate((startingDate.getDate() + (7 + nearestDay - startingDate.getDay()) % 7) - 7 - 7);

    } else {

      nearestTime.setDate(startingDate.getDate() + (7 + nearestDay - startingDate.getDay()) % 7 - 7);

    }

    return nearestTime;
}

// For a given today and last event finds closest next event from today.
// Assumption is that event is recurring every 14 days
function nextEvent(today, event) {
    var eventRecurrence = 14; // recurrence of the event in days
    var nextEventTime = new Date(today.getTime());
    nextEventTime.setDate(today.getDate() + ((today.getDate() > event.getDate()) ? eventRecurrence : 0) - (today.getDate() - event.getDate()) % eventRecurrence);
    return nextEventTime;
}

// Format date as needed for display
function getMonthAndDay(date) {

    // Array to store month names for translation
    monthNames = ['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'Mar.', 'Apr.', 'May', 'Jun.', 'Jul.', 'Aug.', 'Sep.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Dec.'];

    return monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate();
}

// Get date object of nearest Friday and Saturday
var friday = dateOfNearestDay(startingDate, 5);
var saturday = dateOfNearestDay(startingDate, 6);

var nextFridayEvent = nextEvent(startingDate, friday);
var nextSaturdayEvent = nextEvent(startingDate, saturday);

// Write months & days of the variables
console.log('Today is ' + getMonthAndDay(startingDate));
console.log('Friday Event ' + getMonthAndDay(friday));
console.log('Saturday Event ' + getMonthAndDay(saturday));
console.log('Next Friday Event ' + getMonthAndDay(nextFridayEvent));
console.log('Next Saturday Event ' + getMonthAndDay(nextSaturdayEvent))
```

I have modified your function `dateOfNearestDay` with 2x`-7` in order to demonstrate events before `today`.